# Where can I get a good text to read up on Complex variables

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, several-complex-variables

I'm doing a study on calculus of complex variables. I started out by reading the topological concepts, curves and region in the complex plane. At the end exercises were given of which I did not know how to solve the following and they fall under loci problems.

> 1. $ |\arg z| < \frac \pi 2 $
> 2. $ - \pi < \Im(z) < \pi $
> 3. $ |z-1| + |z+1| = 3 $

Here's my attempt

> $ | z - 1 | + | z + 1 | = 3 $
> $ | z + 1 | = 3 - | z + 1 | $
> Squaring both sides
> $ | z + 1 | ^ 2 = 9 - 6 | z - 1 | + | z - 1 | ^ 2 $
> Simplifying
> $ 4 x = 9 - 6 | z - 1 | $
> Squaring again and simplifying
> $ - 10 x ^ 2 + 6 y ^ 2 + 60 x = 75 $
> and quite a few others.

Please I need a guide as the text I'm studying with did not provide sufficient information for me to be able to solve these problems. If I can get a reference material to read up on to solidify my knowledge in this area I'll be grateful. Also if I can get the solution to the problems I'll also appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: The argument of $z$ is the angle (so it's a real number!) the complex number, seen as a vector, makes with the positive x-axis. Essentially you want the argument to be between $-pi/2$ and $pi/2$ due to absolute value. What quadrants are we talking about then?

Comment: You should search Google for argument of complex number and distance between two complex numbers.

Comment: I have searched Google already.  What I don't understand is how to get the loci of an arg of z in a modulus

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ As mentioned by @imranfat in the comments, the argument of $z$ is the angle between the positive real axis and the line joining the point to the origin, so since you want $-\frac{\pi}{2}<arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}$, these are covered in the $1^{st}$ and $4^{th}$ [quadrants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry)).

$2)$ Setting $z=x+iy$, it is clear that you want $-\pi <y<\pi$.

$3)$ Again we set $z=x+iy$ so that $|z|^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}$ and we perform some algebraic manipulation. Squaring both sides gives:

$$9=(|z+1|+|z-1|)^{2}=|z+1|^{2}+|z-1|^{2}+2|z-1||z+1|=(x+1)^{2}+y^{2}+(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}+2|(x+iy)^{2}-1|=2x^{2}+2y^{2}+2+2\sqrt{(x^{2}-y^{2}-1)^{2}+(2xy)^{2}}$$ and now we divide both sides by 2 and re-arrange:
$$\frac{9}{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}-1=\sqrt{(x^{2}-y^{2}-1)^{2}+(2xy)^{2}}$$ and finally we square both sides and collect like terms:

$$0=(x^{2}-y^{2}-1)^{2}+(2xy)^{2}-(x^{2}+y^{2}-\frac{7}{2})^{2}=\frac{1}{4}(20x^{2}+36y^{2}-45).$$

Thus the required answer is all points which satisfy $20x^{2}+36^{2}=45$, which is an [ellipse](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bsxgb3l2gg), centred at the origin with foci at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than posting complete solution. Also, ask OP for their attempt or what more they know about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).